# Connection code to connect iphone to web server

Tags: iphone

Can anyone help me to connect iphone to web server??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always use NSURLRequest to build your request and NSURLConnection to start the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for example as a library (to make it easier).
You can even send POST requests to the website with the encoded parameters (see the documentation on the website).

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Istvan, use ASIHTTPRequest for you calls.  If you want more detail on how to write a local API in Objective-C, I wrote a blog post about this (uses ASIHTTPRequest as well, but is more about program design than the API itself):

http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/10/15/how-to-consume-json-or-xml-web-apis-on-iphone-smoothly/

Answer (score 0):

Use this NSXMLParser Delegate method too

-(void)parseWithContentsofUrl:(NSURL*)url
{

```
isParsingFinished = false;
rssParser = [[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url] autorelease];
[rssParser setDelegate:self];
[rssParser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
[rssParser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
[rssParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
[rssParser parse];
```

}